# Android WebView can't be scrolled after being set to a touch listener

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

#### Expected Result

Web view can be scrolled and can respond to gestures such as move or fling.

What I want to realize is something like the Facebook app. Say we have a content view made up of a control bar (in the upper part right below the status bar) and a web view that show some web page. In the upper control bar there is a menu toggle button in the upper left corner, that can toggle on and off the menu pane view.

The menu is shown by moving the content view rightward, and is hidden by moving the content view back to its original position.

Instead of clicking the menu toggle button, a fling or drag of the web view will also be implemented to hide the menu.

#### Problem

Nothing happened when I tried to scroll in the web view after setting the web view to a touch listener.

#### Source Code

**`MainActivity.java`**

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnGestureListener {

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // WebView
    WebView mWebViewContentRight = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view_content_right);
    mWebViewContentRight.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebViewContentRight.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebViewContentRight.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    mWebViewContentRight.loadUrl("http://m.com2us.com");
    mWebViewContentRight.setOnTouchListener(this);

    // Gesture detector
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    
    // Dismiss shown keyboard
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

    // Implements View.OnTouchListener
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    
    view = (View) view.getParent(); // i.e. linear_layout_content_right
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams(); 

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            _xDelta = X - mLayoutParams.leftMargin;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (isMenuHidden == true) {
                if (((X - _xDelta) < -384) || ((X - _xDelta) > 0)) {
                    // The move allows at most 480 * 80% = 384 pixels leftward and zero pixels rightward
                } else {
                    // TODO : Implement later
                }

            } else { // isMenuHidden == false
                if (((X - _xDelta) < -384) || ((X - _xDelta) > 0)) {
                    // The move allows at most 480 * 80% = 384 pixels leftward and zero pixels rightward
                } else {
                    mLayoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                    view.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
                    
                    if (mLayoutParams.leftMargin <= -192) {
                        mLayoutParams.leftMargin = -384;
                        view.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
                        isMenuHidden = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
    //return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
// End of Implementation of View.OnTouchListener public methods

}
```

---

**`activity_mail.xml`**

```
    <!-- Content view including a control bar 329dp wide by 40dp high,
           and a web view 329dp wide by 509dp high.

           Screen size is 329dp (width by 549dp (height).
           where the menu takes 80% of the width, that is, 263.2dp.

           There is an invisible view as a placeholder above the menu
           and to the left of the content view, which may be not necessary,
           but this is my way to implement it.
    -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_content_right"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="549dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-263.2dp"
        android:background="#FF0099FF"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- The Menu button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_menu"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:onClick="onButtonMenuClicked"
            android:text="@string/button_menu" />

        <!-- The WebView -->
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view_content_right"
            android:layout_width="329dp"
            android:layout_height="509dp"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" />

    </LinearLayout> <!-- End of Content right -->
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do u want to achieve by adding Touch listener. Explain your question!!! If you want to add zooming capacity u can use this method `mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`

Comment: We need more of your abbreviated code. As far as I'm concerned, it's the expected behavior that nothing happens since you omitted the code that loads anything into the webview. And I can't tell you anything more without seeing more of the code.

Comment: @BlackDevil I've added more of my purpose, please check it.

Comment: What are you doing with hard-coded dimension ?!

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I've added some detail.

Comment: @StephaneMathis I don't know what's the better way, like a general solution on dimention. But for now, let's focus on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to see your implementation of the touch listener. It looks like you're consuming the event by returning `true` in `onTouch`.

More details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29).

Comment: Oh you're awesome, case closed!! I'm wondering what does "the event is consumed by the listener" mean? Any reference?

Comment: I still need to post my onTouch() code. Please have a look then.

Comment: "the event is consumed by the listener" i.e. return true, tells the caller that no further work need be done with the touch event. Return false if there's more to do still, i.e. the listener openly doesn't promise to take care of everything i.e. doesn't consume the event.